# Is there a way to programmatically clear an input's value without binding it to the model?

Tags: elm

When I need the ability to programmatically control the value of an input (for example to clear it or set it to a default value) I have to bind a value from my model to it. This creates a two-way binding between the model and the input which causes problems in certain scenarios. In particular, if I have a DOM heavy application, typing fast in an input with this sort of two-way binding can miss keystrokes.

[Here's an example of a one-way binding](https://ellie-app.com/37bTDwmSPKba1/0), using an input event to update the model. Note that I have no programmatic control over the element's value in this example.

[Here's an example of the aforementioned 2-way binding scenario](https://ellie-app.com/37bTDwmSPKba1/1). Here the input event updates the model, which then updates the input's value. This sort of two-way binding is not ideal.

**So my question is:** Is there a way to programmatically clear an input's value without binding it to the model without resorting to something hacky like ports?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to include a Boolean, called `cleared`, for example, in your model. If cleared is True, in your view function bind the `value` of your input field to the empty string. Otherwise, don't include an explicit `value` binding:

```
 input (if model.cleared then [value ""] else []) []
```

In `update`, set `cleared` to True when you want to clear the input; when the textbox gains focus (use `onFocus`), set it back to False.

Comment: I'll give this a try and see how it feels!

Comment: Not sure it's really any less hack-y than using a port, but here's a working demo: https://ellie-app.com/37J3dgCFFFDa1/0 :-)

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is having a possibility of clearing the input text, take a look at this: https://ellie-app.com/4mxTRZqRxa1/0

The basic concept is that there is no `value model` binding unless the `model == ""`. It's a variation on @alex-lew solution described here previously, but instead of introducing a special flag, the `model == ""` is the special flag by itself.

Answer (score 0):

In all cases I've seen of people reporting sluggishness in a DOM-heavy app, it's been in the context of running under Reactor (which by default compiles w/ --debug), or otherwise explicitly running in debug mode. Running in non-debug mode has eliminated it.

In gnarly cases, use Html.Lazy and Html.Keyed.

To answer your specific question of setting on a DOM element a value not reflected in the model ... I don't see a pure elm TEA way of doing it. (I suppose you could rig up a mechanism using animation frames, but it seems far more bother than it's worth.)

Comment: Yes, I've noticed it specifically when I have the chrome debugger open. Should that matter though? It results in non-deterministic behavior, breaking the abstraction. Being sluggish is one thing; Being broken, even if only in extreme cases, is what I'm concerned about.

Comment: It isn't the browser's debugger; it's Elm's own debugging mechanism which when turned on stores every interaction for possible replay and then runs into issues w/ memory. If the issue persists after eliminating --debug, in cases I've seen people have used Html.Lazy and reported good results.

Comment: I did not have Elm's debugger enabled when I observed this behavior.

Comment: I assume you know the following, but to make the distinction: using the Elm "debugger" is different from compiling Elm with the --debug flag. It's the latter that can lead to memory-related sluggishness, and elm-reactor runs w/ --debug by default. So, back to, if you've eliminated --debug as the source of issues the next step would be to investigate using Html.Keyed/Lazy.